# Merge con GIT problemas con fin de lineas

Tags: java, git, git-merge

Tenemos problemas para mezclar ramas de GIT debido a que otros usuarios han subido cambios con otro formato de archivo (distinto fin de línea) . El problema es que al mezclar con otras ramas que tienen fin de línea diferente, da como conflicto todo el fichero. ¿Es posible utilizar algo en el comando merge de git en línea de comandos para que en las mezclas no tenga en cuenta los saltos de línea? Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Lo que buscas es el parámetro de [configuración de git usando `core.autocrlf`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

Comment: Esto lo estoy escribiendo sobre el tema http://www.ezconflict.com/es/conflicts_esse16.html#x81-1200003.2

Answer (score 0):

Puntualmente, sobre tu pregunta... si, puedes pedirle a git que mezcle evitando fijarse en el forma de los saltos de línea.

```
git merge -Xignore-space-at-eol
```

Pero los archivos con formatos de salto de línea diferentes van a terminar como un frankenstein con formatos de salto de linea diferentes *dentro de ellos*. Unas líneas terminan con un formato y otras líneas con otros. Y eso te garantiza que **siempre** vas a tener que utilizar esa opción para hacer operaciones de mezcla a futuro si hay modificaciones (así sean triviales) en dichos archivos. Otras operaciones frecuentes como rebase, cherry-pick no se si tengan el soporte. En fin, si decides mantener la historia con los cambios de salto de línea, te aseguras un futuro de horror innecesario. Te recomendaría arreglar la historia de esos archivos en las ramas respectivas antes de mezclar. En este artículo explico los detalles del problema y una forma de arreglar la historia de esas ramas antes de mezclarlas con *relativamente* poco esfuerzo.

http://www.ezconflict.com/es/conflicts_esse16.html#x81-1200003.2